# rosrun can't find executables even though {workspace_directory}/devel/setup.bash was sourced correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ros

I have sourced the /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash and my workspace correctly. But still I can't find my nodes inside the package throgh autocompletion (pressing TAB key). If I type in the name manually, it returns a error saying "[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named raspicam_node below"

I looked in CMakeFiles and everything was formatted correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled read-write permission in the workspace directory.

```
$ chmod u+x -R {workspace_directory}
```

Running this before I wanted to run a node fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have given execution as well as read/write permissions in the cmake directory or where the nodes are located.

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R {directory}
```

Try and run this before you execute the files.
Or configure the setup bash again.